# Is there any value for what x === x returns false without NaN?

Tags: javascript

Is there any value for what `x === x` returns `false` without NaN?

For example:

```
> x = 1
1
> x === x
true
> x = {}
{}
> x === x
true
> x = new Date()
Wed Nov 13 2013 15:44:22 GMT+0200 (EET)
> x === x
true
> x = NaN
NaN
> x === x
false
```

I see that the only value where `x === x` returns `false` is when `isNaN(x) === true`.

Is there another value of `x` for what `x === x` returns `false`? An official reference would be welcome!

Comment: And what is `x`? Maybe use `x` and `y` or something in your example.

Comment: @putvande A variable?

Comment: The answer is no, but i can't look for a reference now.

Comment: @Tibos Yes, that would be useful.

Comment: @イオニカビザウ Your profile message widget is really interesting! Is the code available anywhere?

Comment: @ComFreek Hahaha, It's not opensource, but that's very simple. Do you want to publish it? Maybe I will...

Comment: @イオニカビザウ No, not publishing, just using it for my own profile (of course with proper attribution) ;)

Comment: @ComFreek Send me (again) your email address.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The strict comparison between two equal non-`NaN` *values* will always be true ([SLaks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19955555/710446) correctly quotes [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)). However, it's possible for the *expression* `x` to change its *value* during the evaluation of the the equality. This can happen with property access when using accessor property descriptors (i.e., property getters):

```
foo = {};
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", {
    get: function() {
        return Math.random();
    }
})

foo.bar === foo.bar; // false
```

If you do this for the global object `window` (or `global` in Node), then you can see the `x === x` comparison fail for a global-scope variable:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "bar", {
    get: function() {
        return Math.random();
    }
})

bar === bar; // false
```

Comment: @ComFreek Well, dang, I hadn't considered that. I'll add that into may answer!

Comment: This isn't a case of the same value; it is a case of the same expression evaluating to different values.

Comment: @ComFreak - My eyes!  The goggles do nothing!

Comment: @YannVernier, yes, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @apsillers This is so nice! Works good with `this` object also both in NodeJS and in browser.

Answer (score 11):

The spec lists the [exact rules](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) for strict equality.
There are no other such cases, unless you count `+0` and `-0`.

The [SameValue algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x9.12) (used for validating changes to read-only defined properties) has no such exceptions.

Comment: Still, `+0 === +0` and `-0 === -0`, so even those are out.

Comment: Per the spec, +0 and -0 do compare equal. However, the spec also does not list all cases of numbers, which is why there is the default of a false return: infinities are not considered equal, even if they share sign.

Comment: @Yann, `1/0 === 1/0` is `true` for me on Firefox.

Comment: `+0 === -0` returns `true`. Why does they matter?

Comment: To clarify: strict equality does not distinguish between `-0` and `+0`, while `SameValue` *does* distinguish.