# When does a !== a?

Tags: javascript

I ran into the expression `a !== a` in someone else's code:

```
function isEmpty(a) {
    return a === undefined || a === '' || a === null || a !== a;
}
```

The only case where I can think of the final expression evaluating to `true` is when `isNaN(a)`. Are there any other values of `a` for which `a !== a` is true?

Comment: Unless you have some additional context, I don't see how this is reasonably on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This mostly covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1026459

Comment: `NaN !== NaN`, but everything else is equal to itself (to my knowledge).

Comment: @apsillers: Thanks, it is indeed a duplicate of that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955493/is-there-any-value-for-what-x-x-returns-false-without-nan also off-topic?

Comment: That question at least has some context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: (edited) Is this better? I'm trying to understand what you mean by context, since I thought my question had enough context before to answer it unambiguously.

Comment: The best context would be the code where you saw the `a !== a`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'll try to include code samples in future questions. Thanks for updating the reason for closure.