# Comparing a variable with itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, polyfills

I stumbled over this polyfill of Array.prototype.includes.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes.
Is there a reason for the comparison of the variables with themselves on line 21,22?

```
if (searchElement === currentElement ||
         (searchElement !== searchElement && currentElement !== currentElement)) {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this second operand of the `||` does check whether both `searchElement` and `currentElement` are [`NaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-nan) - the [only value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19955493/1048572) in JavaScript that is not `===` to itself. `includes` is supposed to use the [*`SameValueZero`* equivalence algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero), which is different from the the [*Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) (used by [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity)) or the [*`SameValue`* algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevalue) (used in [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)).