# what is the purpose of this logical-and-followed-by-strict-equality javascript idiom?

Tags: javascript, lodash, operator-precedence

I was poking around the [lodash repo](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) and [found](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2da024c3b4f9947a48517639de7560457cd4ec6c/.internal/baseDifference.js#L47) the following:

```js
if (isCommon && computed === computed) {
     <stuff>
}
```

Here,

- `isCommon` is a boolean [initially set](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2da024c3b4f9947a48517639de7560457cd4ec6c/.internal/baseDifference.js#L23) to `true` and then reset to `false` conditionally on some checks;
- while `computed` is obtained by [iterating](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2da024c3b4f9947a48517639de7560457cd4ec6c/.internal/baseDifference.js#L43) over an array (`for (let value of array)`) and possibly applying a function `iteratee` to the current value `value`.

**My question**:

Why is that `if` clause not simply `if (isCommon)`?

**Elaboration (of one possible answer)**

The `Mozilla` [operator-precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) tells me that

- strict equality `===` has precedence 11,
- higher than the precedence of 7 for the `&&` operator

This means, presumably, that the boolean check inside the `if` is parsed as `isCommon && (computed === computed)`.

Most of the time that second arm will be true, as `x === x` even for funky "values" like `null` or `undefined`. The only other option I can think of is that applying the function `iteratee` to `value` to produce `computed` might make a [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). In that case the strict equality will evaluate to false; in `node`:

```
> x=Math.abs("boo"); 1 && x === x
false
```

Is this it? Is the somewhat strange (to me) shape of the `if` clause meant to guard against this eventuality?

Comment: The only thing that jumps to mind is that perhaps it relates to something like checking for  `NaN` in a legacy way?

Comment: Thanks: `NaN` is what came to my mind too, as mentioned. Someone seems to have suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27144366/11064961), which makes the same suggestion. My question was more along the lines of "what else could this be for", but I suppose closing it is fair enough.